# Could not switch to new window and verify content using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a saas application using Selenium Python, and in that i need to verify a new window content, after clicking on the button. Below is the screenshot of the window.

[image]

In the Image, i am clicking on the Printable Version button, the new window is the with title about:blank - Google Chrome.

I tried the below codes, but none of them worked,

```
all_windows = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_windows[1])
```

i tried this also

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

i even tried to loop and find out but did not work

```
all_windows = driver.window_handles
for window_handle in all_windows:
    if window_handle != driver.current_window_handle:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break
```

all the codes freeze when trying to switch to the newly opened window.  The system timesout without executing any other code.

Any idea will be helpful

Comment: i found out that, it switches to the new window but does not identify anything inside it.   Not even drive.title